# create a image with color in android

Tags: android, image, colors

Setting background doesn't seem to give any hint on size for android.
Hence I'm looking for a way to create an image with a specific color.
(would be better if could be done in xml)

in iOS this could be achieved by

```
+ (UIImage*)placeHolderImage
{
    static UIImage* image = nil;
    if(image != nil)
        return image;

    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // Seashell color                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    UIColor* color = [UIColor colorWithRed:255/255.0 green:245/255.0 blue:238/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [color CGColor]);
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);

    image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused by what you are trying to accomplish. How is color related to size? Have you tried using an Image in your axml layout file and specifying the width and height explicitly?

Comment: I have a list view with images. When I don't set src, the image view first have width 0(hence making the row collapsed) and when image is set, its height changes..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is the equivalent *Android* code:

```
// CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, 1, 1);

//UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
//CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
Bitmap image = Bitmap.createBitmap(rect.width(), rect.height(), Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(image);

//UIColor* color = [UIColor colorWithRed:255/255.0 green:245/255.0 blue:238/255.0 alpha:1.0];
int color = Color.argb(255, 255, 245, 238);

//CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [color CGColor]);
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setColor(color);

//CGContextFillRect(context, rect);
canvas.drawRect(rect, paint);

//image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
//UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
/** nothing to do here, we already have our image **/
/** and the canvas will be released by the GC     **/
```

Now, if you want to do this in *XML* its much easier:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <size android:width="1px" android:height="1dp"/>
    <solid android:color="#FFFFF5EE/>
</shape>
```

Although that won't give you a `Bitmap`, but a `Drawable`. It's just fine if you intend to just draw it somewhere. If you actually need a `Bitmap`, then you will have to use the above code to create a `Canvas` from a `Bitmap` and draw your `Drawable` into it.

Comment: Nice comparison of ios and android!

Answer (score -3):

This helps you in creating a bitmap image with a specific color.
firstly create a bitmap with name sampleBitmap like below

```
Bitmap.Config conf = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888; // see other conf types
Bitmap sampleBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(300, 300, conf); // this creates a MUTABLE bitmap
```

next use the following code to get each pixel of the created bitmap

// int[] pixels = new int[sampleBitmap.getHeight()*sampleBitmap.getWidth()];

```
for (int i=0; i < sampleBitmap.getWidth(); i++)
{
for (int j=0; j < sampleBitmap.getHeight(); i++)
 {
    sampleBitmap.setPixel(i, j, Color.rgb(someColor1, someColor2, someColor3));
 }
}
```

using this you can set the bitmap to the listview item so that the listitem doesnt collapse

Comment: i just suggested a way that could be possible and which i am aware of.

Comment: Sure, just pointing out that from the possible ways this one is the worst. A similar yet much better approach is to actually set the image pixels into the `pixels` array you declared but not used, and then do a _single_ call to `setPixels`.

Comment: downvoters.. As I already commented, this is one way that I am aware of and yes there is a better answer. I am not sure if its a good thing to downvote after saying that it is one way that I am aware of.